# Swift: Create multiple UIImageView copies along touchesMoved path

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, touchesmoved

I'm new to swift and have been playing around with this code all day.  I think I know where the problem is, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it.  I have a view controller that contains a UIImageView and I'm looking to simply make multiple copies of the same UIImageView at each touch point as the user enters the touchesMoved function.  I created an array to store the elements of all the locations the user had touched and used array.append in the touchesMoved function to collect the points.  I then created a loop that would read in these CGPoints and assign a UIImageView to the point.  The problem is that CGPoints are not convertible to UIImageViews.  Any suggestions on how I can go about this problem?

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var wayPoints: [CGPoint] = []
    var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    @IBOutlet var Person : UIImageView!

    func movePoint (){
        for var i = 0; i < wayPoints.count; ++i {
            let p = wayPoints[i]

            if i == 0 {
                CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)
            }
            else {
                CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)
            }

            var Person = wayPoints[i]

        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        Person.center = location

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
        location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        Person.center = location
        wayPoints.append(location)

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Person.center = CGPointMake(0, 0)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[edit]

This is a bit different approach using CALayer.  I used it because 1. I found that UIImageView copies would mean poor performance and 2. for every five layer copies I make, I want to be able to animate the contentsScale of the layer by 120%.  I realize the animation right now is for cornerRadius but that's the only animation that I got to work.  The syntax is alright, but I think my semantics are still a bit off.  The image follows my cursor while I drag and I think layers are being created because there's just a little bit of lag in the trail.  I just can't seem to get images to populate in the layers to actually form the path that the user dragged along.  I would appreciate help while I try this new approach.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let imageLayer = CALayer()
let image = UIImage(named: "at")!
var wayPoints: [CGPoint] = []
var layers: [CALayer] = []
var images: [UIImage] = []
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func setup() {
    imageLayer.contents = image.CGImage

    imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

    // Round corners
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = 25

    // Set border
    imageLayer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    imageLayer.borderWidth = 10

    imageLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    imageLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    imageLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2)
    imageLayer.shadowRadius = 3

    imageLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    imageLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect
    imageLayer.contentsScale = imageLayer.contentsScale
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

    for var i = 0; i < wayPoints.count; ++i {

        let p = wayPoints[i]

        if i == 0 {
            CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)
        }
        else {
            CGPointMake(p.x, p.y)
        }

        var newLayer = CALayer()
        newLayer.position = wayPoints[i]
        var newImage = UIImage(named: "at")!
        newLayer.contents = newImage.CGImage

        layers.append(newLayer)
        images.append(newImage)


        }

}

// Animate button would trigger this function to fire
func animate(){
    for (index, value) in enumerate(layers){
            if index % 5 == 0 {
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")

                animation.fromValue = value.cornerRadius

                animation.toValue = 0

                animation.repeatCount = 1000

                imageLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")
            }

            else {
                let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")

                animation.fromValue = value.cornerRadius

                animation.toValue = 25

                animation.repeatCount = 1000

                imageLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "cornerRadius")

        }


    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    imageLayer.position = location
    setup()

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch! = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    //        var point: CGPoint = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    wayPoints.append(location)
    setup()
    imageLayer.position = location

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `var Person = waypoints[i]` line and replace it with something like:

```
for (n, child) in enumerate(containerView.subviews) {
    (child as UIView).removeFromSuperview()
}
var newPerson = UIImageView(image: Person.image)
newPerson.position = waypoints[i]
containerView.addSubview(newPerson)
```

Where `containerView` is a UIView you set up for the purpose of containing your image views.

As a side note: please don't name your variables with UpperCase names, those should be reserved for types (classes protocols, structs, etc)

Comment: Dont forget to add it to your self.view as well

Comment: My code displays an alert saying that UIImage does not have a member named 'position'.  Any solutions?  Or should I just approach the entire problem using CALayers (if I want to animate the individual layers)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like you are moving the existing image than creating new ones.

Do what @joshua said but make sure you actually call your movePoint() method inside touchesMoved(). Now it never gets called.

As a side note, depending on the image you are using and other context dependent variables, what you are trying to do could produce a "sluggish/slow" result.

Comment: I agree...my solution is easy to understand, but would have HORRIBLE performance. It would probably be a lot better to use QuartzCore and draw the image repeatedly to a "canvas" image.

Comment: Using CGLayer objects would most likely improve performance/drawing time, would it not?  According to the Apple's documentation, CGLayerRefs are good for "repeated drawing. For example, [creating] a pattern that consists of the same item drawn over and over."  Since that's what everyone recommends for performance reasons, I'll rewrite some code and see if it can't be done another way.  Thanks.